# rewrite/redirect url from subdomain to domain with wildcard?

Tags: redirect

I just moved a site from a sub folder to the html root and i need to have some sort of htaccess rule to rewrite all urls so old links to the site still work

The old path is www.domain.com/stage/*
and should point now to www.domain.com/*

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of Webserver are you using, should look something like

```
rewrite ^(.+)/stage/(.*)$  $1/$2;
```

Let me know if you need any refinements or if you need it for a specific Webserver

Comment: Thanx! Apache
this worked too 

`RedirectMatch 301 /stage/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1`

Comment: I would try and avoid hardcoding the domain if I were you (what about www?), just match the beginning of the URL the same way that you did for the end.